# Transforming a list with a list inside of it to a string

Tags: python

I have this list:

```
l = [['a', ['b'], 'c', 'd', 'e'], ['f', ['g'], 'h', 'i', 'j'], ['k', 'l', 'n', 'o', 'p'], ['q', ['r'], 's', 't', 'u']]
```

I want to transform it to this string:

```
a;b;c;d;e;f;g;h;i .....
```

I tried doing this:

```
  flat_list = [item for sublist in l for item in sublist]
    return flat_list
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str%20join#str.join), first joining the elements of the inner lists by `&` and then the outer list by `\n`:

```
out = '\n'.join(';'.join(','.join(e) if type(e) is list else e for e in s) for s in l)
print(out)
```

Output:

```
Holding Out;Bonnie Tyler;Secret Dreams and Forbidden Fire;Country-Pop-Rock;5:50
Poker Face;Lady Gaga;The Fame;Pop;3:59
Another One Bites the Dust;Queen;The Game;Funk rock;3:36
Nothing Else Matters;Metallica;Metallica;Rock-Heavy metal;6:29
```

Note that when the artist is a list, I've joined it with `,`. So when there are multiple artists on a track, for example `['Billy Joel', 'Ray Charles']`, they will appear in the list as

```
... ;Billy Joel,Ray Charles; ...
```

Comment: @bigbounty the join by `,` was for lists of artists; it needs to not be a `;` as that would create a new field. See my note after the sample output

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
l = [['Holding Out', ['Bonnie Tyler'], 'Secret Dreams and Forbidden Fire', 'Country-Pop-Rock', '5:50'], ['Poker Face', ['Lady Gaga'], 'The Fame', 'Pop', '3:59'], ['Another One Bites the Dust', 'Queen', 'The Game', 'Funk rock', '3:36'], ['Nothing Else Matters', ['Metallica'], 'Metallica', 'Rock-Heavy metal', '6:29']]

l = '\n'.join(';'.join(s
                       if isinstance(s,str)
                       else s[0]
                       for s in t)
                       for t in l)
print(l)
```

Output:

```
Holding Out;Bonnie Tyler;Secret Dreams and Forbidden Fire;Country-Pop-Rock;5:50
Poker Face;Lady Gaga;The Fame;Pop;3:59
Another One Bites the Dust;Queen;The Game;Funk rock;3:36
Nothing Else Matters;Metallica;Metallica;Rock-Heavy metal;6:29
```

Comment: @Nick I used `isinstance()`. The OP never specified that the most internal lists would be joined with commas.

Comment: I didn't notice you had used `isinstance()` when I made that comment. I will retract it. Note it was not my downvote...

Comment: This doesn't deserve to have a worse score than the recent answer.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't really flat the list, and may need use `join` to Concatenate strings by seperator. Here one function provided to flat any list

```py
def flat(sequence):
    """
    Function to flat multi-dimensional list to 1D list
    : Parameters
      sequence: list to flat
    : Return
      1D list, or sequence if sequence is not a list
    """
    result = []
    if isinstance(sequence, list):
        for item in sequence:
            if isinstance(item, list):
                result += flat(item)
            else:
                result.append(item)
        return result
    else:
        return sequence
```

then you can get 2nd level flat by

```py
>>> flat_list = [flat(item) for item in l]
>>> flat_list
[['Holding Out',
  'Bonnie Tyler',
  'Secret Dreams and Forbidden Fire',
  'Country-Pop-Rock',
  '5:50'],
 ['Poker Face', 'Lady Gaga', 'The Fame', 'Pop', '3:59'],
 ['Another One Bites the Dust', 'Queen', 'The Game', 'Funk rock', '3:36'],
 ['Nothing Else Matters', 'Metallica', 'Metallica', 'Rock-Heavy metal', '6:29']]
```

For your request to text output

```py
>>> text = '\n'.join(';'.join(item) for item in flat_list)
>>> print(text)
Holding Out;Bonnie Tyler;Secret Dreams and Forbidden Fire;Country-Pop-Rock;5:50
Poker Face;Lady Gaga;The Fame;Pop;3:59
Another One Bites the Dust;Queen;The Game;Funk rock;3:36
Nothing Else Matters;Metallica;Metallica;Rock-Heavy metal;6:29
```